# R - missing imputation with MICE: POST processing for all variables at once

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I have a question for MICE /MICEADDS imputation.
I have #metabolomics dataset, where all my variabes MUST be a positive value (peak intensities are never < 0).
I wish to set the POST that correct all negative imputations in positive values. I set "POST" for only one variable: met1, but I want the rule works for all of them at the same time (I have usually some hundreds of variables). In example below I selected the range to be picked for negatives.

```
post<-init$post
post["met1"] <-
  "imp[[j]][, i] <- squeeze(imp[[j]][, i], c(29, 7879460))"
```

or

```
post["met1"] <- "ifdo(c(met1 < 29, met1 > 7879460), c(29, 7879460))"
```

Could you help me please, with setting it better.
thank you,
Mary

This is how the dataframe look like: Two diets, several timepoints for each participant.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5ztP.png)

Comment: Since you have so many variables, perhaps illustrating your question with more than only one of them could make your needs clearer.

Comment: Next time, you shouldn't post data as an image.

Answer (score 0):

> I set "POST" for only one variable: met1, but I want the rule works for all of them at the same time

You can easily set the post-processing of the first fifteen variables (`met1` to `met15` in *the dataframe*) at once with:

```
post[1:15] <- "imp[[j]][, i] <- squeeze(imp[[j]][, i], c(29, 7879460))"
```